Backlight not working on Lenovo V15 G4 IRU
The following problem occurs on a Lenovo V15 G4 IRU, BIOS Version: MCCN26WW, BIOS Release Date: 02/22/2024, while trying to install Debian 12.7.0. Before the installation, I have run FTWS V24.07.00. The filtered output of the file "results.log" gives me some information, e.g.

Test 194 of 209: Test BCL (Query List of Brightness Control Levels Supported).
Brightness levels for _SB.PC00.GFX0.DD1F.BCL:
Level on full power   : 80
Level on battery power: 50
Brightness Levels     : 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100
PASSED: Test 194, _SB.PC00.GFX0.DD1F.BCL returned a sane package of 103
integers.
Brightness levels for _SB.PC00.GFX0.DD2F.BCL:
Level on full power   : 80
Level on battery power: 50
Brightness Levels     : 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100
PASSED: Test 194, _SB.PC00.GFX0.DD2F._BCL returned a sane package of 103
integers.

Test 195 of 209: Test _BCM (Set Brightness Level).
PASSED: Test 195, \_SB_.PC00.GFX0.DD1F._BCM returned no values as expected.
PASSED: Test 195, \_SB_.PC00.GFX0.DD2F._BCM returned no values as expected.

Test 196 of 209: Test _BQC (Brightness Query Current Level).
PASSED: Test 196, \_SB_.PC00.GFX0.DD1F._BQC correctly returned an integer.
PASSED: Test 196, \_SB_.PC00.GFX0.DD2F._BQC correctly returned an integer.

Because the brightness control did not work as expected after the installation of Debian, I have inserted the following kernel options at boot time: "acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor". Further, I have set "Handle display brightness keys" to on in the xfce4-power-manager window.
Now, after ensuring that the LED is on in the ESC key, I press the Fn and the corresponding F.. keys for darker or brighter. A little popup window appears with a bar which length depends on the number of pressing these keys. But the background brightness does NOT change.
What is wrong ? How can I change it ?

Had a similar issue and use xrandr to control brightness: http://sandipbgt.com/2015/10/01/control-screen-brightness-from-commandline-in-ubuntu/ Added keyboard shortcuts to script, and it works well. xgamma is also very useful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/756082/how-to-adjust-screen-settings-contrast-color-saturation-etc
